# Are WebSockets not supported in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, websocket

I'm running Firefox 7 in Ubuntu 11.04, and I noticed socket.io was falling back from web sockets to xhr-polling, so I typed `WebSocket` in Firefox's console, and got

```
[00:48:21.224] ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined
```

On Google Chrome 14 I got

```
WebSocket
function WebSocket() { [native code] }
```

According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets), WebSockets is partly supported since firefox 4 and fully supported since firefox 6.

Is it only different in firefox on linux ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Firefox 4/5, WebSockets support is present but disabled (activated via about:config). In Firefox 6, Mozilla enabled WebSockets by default but added the "Moz" prefix. Also, note that Firefox 6 uses the newer HyBi protocol and W3C API. Chrome added the HyBi protocol in Chrome 14 although Chrome has never used a prefix.

The protocol is effectively complete and the official first version is expected to be published in about 6 weeks (the wire format has not changed significantly in months). The API has also been quite stable for months and Chrome 14+ and Firefox 6+ basically have the same implementation of the API. For some reason Mozilla has chosen to be even more cautious than normal with WebSockets prefixing. Perhaps it is a reaction to Google not being careful enough about prefixing unstable APIs.

Unless you are interested in binary message support, specific error and close condition handling or sub-protocol selection, then the WebSockets API has been essentially the same since Chrome introduced it a couple of years ago. If you are implementing a WebSockets server then you will need to know about the various versions of the protocol which has seen significant changes in the past 2 years.

Comment: FIREFOX 7 supports hybi-10; not Firefox 6.

Comment: @Roger, Firefox 6 supports HyBi-06. There is very little wire-level protocol difference between any of the recent HyBi protocol spec releases (HyBi 06-17). The are really two WebSocket protocols: Hixie and HyBi (HyBi-00 is just a copy of Hixie-76). Hixie-76 is pretty similar to Hixie-75 but involved a new handshake challenge. HyBi introduced a completely new framing format (including client-server payload masking) and significantly changed the handshake. Those changes were made early on in the HyBi series. Since then it's mostly been spec text refactoring (with minor wire format tweaks).

Comment: There was a major difference between Firefox 6 and 7.

Comment: @Roger, no, there were a couple of minor differences in the protocol. Here is a [diff of the handshake](https://gist.github.com/1958242). No interesting differences. Sec-WebSocket-Extension was optional and an interim idea that went away and was not implemented on the server side. The framing is identical. The only actual differences were some minor changes to close status codes (not breaking changes). Compare: [HyBi 7](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-07) to [HyBi 8](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-08)

Comment: It's a question of whether it works or not; not how great the difference in details.

Comment: @RogerF.Gay, there are no differences significant enough to prevent it from working. Therefore firefox 6 and 7 are effectively the same for the purposes of the question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try `MozWebSocket` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets#AutoCompatibilityTable

Comment: If you mean "like what Chrome implements", then "maybe".  Chrome's behavior has actually changed over different versions, because the spec is still in flux.  That's why Mozilla's implementation is prefixed: the behavior is not finalized yet.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 7 supports hybi-10 "straight out of the box." I've been running it against my Firefox 7 supports hybi-10 "straight out of the box." I've been running it against my websocket server. You can try my online demo with Firefox 7 and let me know if you have any problem. I've tested it from Ubuntu 11. I have that set up right now.

Comment: I updated the out-of-date web address for the demo: Also, here's a blog article that goes with it. http://highlevellogic.blogspot.se/2011/09/websocket-server-demonstration_26.html