# Linux - WebSocket test error

Tags: javascript, html, linux, websocket

I am testing on opening websocket and echo. 
I am trying to run on Linux-based PC and testing with example code in the official websocket website 'http://www.websocket.org/echo.html'
I just copied the code there and saved as HTML file. But, when I access
'127.0.0.1/websocket.html' , only HTML code is appeared on the screen, no working with JavaScript file. I tried exact same code with my laptop which is window-based, it works correctly. I am using a web browser as "Chromium 10.0.648.133 Ubuntu 10.04"
Can you please help me out? The code is here below..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WebSocket Test</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var wsUri = "ws://echo.websocket.org/";
    var output;

    function init() {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
testWebSocket();


}

function testWebSocket() {
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
}

function onOpen(evt) {
writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
doSend("WebSocket rocks");
}

function onClose(evt) {
writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
}

function onMessage(evt) {
writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
websocket.close();
}

function onError(evt) {
writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
}

function doSend(message) {
writeToScreen("SENT: " + message);
websocket.send(message);
}

function writeToScreen(message) {
var pre = document.createElement("p");
pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
pre.innerHTML = message;
output.appendChild(pre);
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

</script>
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this example should work? Last time I've try to run it I've got an error (because standard have changed). I've started my own C-based websocket library, but still had no time to finish it.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this code works. You just copied this code and save as xxx.html and open it with your browser. then you will see the result.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you've trying to run websockets server on your computer. The site by link works pretty well both in firefox and chrome.

Comment: Yes, but do you know why the guy answered below are talking about firefox? dont i use chrome now ?

Comment: I don't understand why you have problem: I've just test your code. All works. Does your browser new enough?

Comment: i dont thinnk it's new enough. but i think i should work with this browser anyway Chromium 10.0.648.133 Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: maybe this line 'window.addEventListener("load", init, false);' does not fit to linux system?

Comment: > "Chromium 10.0.648.133" - this is too old browser. It seems that it doesn't support websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system has absolutely nothing to do with WebSocket working or not. This is a browser issue. Firefox, Chromium or whatever provide the same features to web developers on every platform they support.

Chromium 10 has only [partial support](http://caniuse.com/websockets) for WebSocket, which means it supports an old version of the standard/protocol or you must enable them manually. Just update your browser. Chromium 10 was released in March 2011 and thus is quite old in this current situation where new HTML5 features are added to almost every browser release.

Answer (score 0):

Are WebSockets not supported in Firefox
[Are WebSockets not supported in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623730/are-websockets-not-supported-in-firefox)

The above link may be helpful for you...

Comment: But, why are you talking about Firefox? The browser I have is "Chromium 10.0.648.133 Ubuntu 10.04" this one which is not firefox, but chrome!