# Decoding node Buffer in browser is empty string

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, buffer

I am using [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) to send binary data to the browser like this:

```
this._conn.sendBytes(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ event, message, error: error, code: -1 })))
```

I then am listening for the message like this:

```
function ABToStr(ab) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(ab))
}

ws.addEventListener('message', e => {
  console.log(e.data, this.ABToStr(e.data))
})
```

In my browser I am getting a `Blob(1638) {size: 1638, type: ""}` and `""`

The data that gets sent is json, because I tested it without sending it as binary, and the json is there and it is valid.

How come when I decode it it is an empty string?

Comment: What is `ab` within `ABToStr`?

Comment: It is the `array buffer` aka `Blob(1638) {size: 1638, type: ""}`

Comment: A `Blob` is not an `ArrayBuffer`. Did you set the `WebSocket`  `.binaryType` to `"arraybuffer"` ?

Comment: Looks like it is an empty buffer console says: `buffer: ArrayBuffer(0)`

Comment: Where are you getting the `Blob` from? What is the `.binaryType` of the `WebSocket` instance set to? You cannot be simultaneously getting a `Blob` and an `ArrayBuffer` at `message` event.

Comment: Looks like setting `ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer'` fixes the issue

Comment: See also [How do I test my WebSocket which is developed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097345/how-do-i-test-my-websocket-which-is-developed-in-javascript/)